# How to flash BIOS on Acer Aspire 5720 ICL50

Tags: bios, acer-aspire, flashing

I have searched every website I can and none of the instructions I have found seem to work for me. The laptop model is Aspire 5720 ICL50, from 2008. The laptop shows black screen when powering on, cant event get the BIOS screen. External monitor does not work. The last BIOS version I know was on it was v1.43, the only version available from Acer is v1.45. The file I downloaded from Acer is an executable(.exe) file. When extracted with 7zip I get a number of files, CL50145A.fd, InsydeFlash.exe, iscflash.dll, iscflash.sys, iscflashx64.sys, platform.ini. I have put the BIOS(.fd) file(1024kB) directly onto a USB pen(tried both FAT and FAT32), burned it directly to a CD, unplugged laptop, battery out, press and hold power button for 30 seconds, insert USB or CD, held Fn+Esc keys, plugged power back in, power button flashes orange once, pressed power button, laptop powers on, fan rotates maximum speed constantly, power button never lights up again, release Fn+Esc keys after about 5 seconds, then waited for between several minutes and several hours, nothing happens, fan continues at full speed, press and hold power button until laptop shuts down. I occasionally hear the CD spin round every few minutes. The laptop originally came with Windows Vista 32 bit, however I have tried removing the hdd from the laptop altogether, still no luck.

How can I flash a BIOS onto this laptop to restore it? Do I have the correct BIOS or do I need the original v1.43. Is my procedure correct? Am I fighting a losing battle?

Any help much appreciated thanks.

Comment: You are not going to be able to flash your BIOS if the system does not even POST.  The files you extracted are designed to be ran from within Windows.  *It sounds like the system is bricked.*

Comment: A quick google search will show you that it is indeed possible to flash a bios outside windows os using a usb pen. Some show renaming the(.fd) with different names, none show any consistency with the renaming.

Comment: I didn't say it was not possible to flash your BIOS outside of Windows.  *I said it's not possible to flash your firmware if the machine is bricked.*  What you describe indicates the system is not even attempting to POST, which means it never attempts to even load the file you are trying to load, which means you won't be able to load it.  *Your motherboard does not have a hardware button to switch to a backup firmware.*